# Java - Unchecked cast from Object to Map.Entry<String,String>

Tags: java, casting, hashtable

I have an "unchecked cast from Object to Map.Entry" on "Map.Entry entry = (Entry) o;"

I think everything is OK and I can put an add suppress warning safely but I'm not sure. Here's my code.

```
public abstract class WebPath {
    protected Hashtable<String, String> wp;

    public String get(String whatDoYouWant) {
        for (Object o : wp.entrySet()) {

            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = (Entry<String, String>) o;
            if (whatDoYouWant.equals(entry.getKey())) {
                return (String) entry.getValue();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you everybody, have a good day !

Comment: BTW Hashtable is a legacy class which was replaced in 1998.  Only use this class if you have an API which requires it.  Use `Map` instead.

Comment: Specifically `HashMap` if you want a hash table implementation.  Also, you  have a redundant cast in your return statement, as your `entry` is typed, the compiler already knows that `entry.getValue()` returns a `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't like it when you take an instance and cast it to a derived class.  This is because you have no guarantee that that instance *is* that derived class.  If you know better such as in your case, that's fine, but it is not best practice in general.

Your wp.entrySet() is returning a Set of Map.Entry.  So use Map.Entry!  Better still if you're not dropping the generic types, so you should have:

```java
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : wp.entrySet()) {
    // ...
}
```

No need to cast it since you know what type it is.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo or a misunderstanding, but the compiler couldn't care less if you cast to a superclass.  That's always safe.  The issue here is that it's an *unchecked* cast, so the choice of type parameters `<String, String>` isn't enforced at runtime like a normal downcast would be (i.e. to a subclass, not a superclass).

Comment: @MarkPeters Oops, I meant to write derived class, not super class.  The issue is not with the generics.  It would give you the same issue if you removed the generics and tried to cast Object to Entry.

Answer (score 6):

Don't suppress the warning, it's giving you good advice!  You are choosing to assign each entry to the uninformative base class `Object`, instead of the more precise type, `Map.Entry<String, String>`.  If you fix your for-loop you will eliminate the warning:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> o : wp.entrySet()) {
```